# Как расположить элементы в html не по сетке?

Tags: html, css

Хотел сверстать страницу, которая будет похожа на картинку. Как можно размещать элементы не по прямой линии, а по кривой?) чтобы можно было заполнить пустоту между кругами. Заранее спасибо
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]